# Accessing Ruby Array as my_array.new_field = "abc"

Tags: ruby

I need to create a new empty object and access its attributes like `my_object.title = 'abc'` as opposed to `my_object[:title] = 'abc'`. How could I do this?

```
my_object = Array.new
my_object.title = "abc"
# => undefined method `title=' for []:Array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Array in Ruby is not like an Array in JavaScript - you can't reference elements by name, but only by index.  What you probably want is a Hash.

```
my_object = {}
my_object['title'] = "abc"
```

Or you can set it at initialization:

```
my_object = {'title' => 'abc'}
```

Alternatively, you can use OpenStruct to assign using dynamic attribute setters as you are doing:

```
my_object = OpenStruct.new
my_object.title = "abc"
```

Comment: perfect, OpenStruct is exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: Note that you have to `require "ostruct"` to get OpenStruct.

Comment: If you know what variables you need to set I would just use the Struct class.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what properties you want the object to have.  You gave the example

```
my_object = Array.new
my_object.title = "abc"
```

If you want your objects to effectively be arrays, having access to all the methods available to arrays, but in addition you want to add additional properties, the way to do that is to create a subclass of `Array`:

```
class MyArray < Array
  attr_accessor :title
  def initialize(*args)
    super
  end
end

MyArray.ancestors    # => [MyArray, Array, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
a = MyArray.new(3,2) # => [2,2,2]
b = MyArray.new      # => []
b << 4 << 5 << 6     # => [4,5,6]
e = a+b              # => [2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6]
e.class              # => Array 
a.title = "This is array a"
puts a.title         # => "This is array a"
e.title = "me, e"    # => NoMethodError: undefined method `title='
b.class              # => MyArray
b.is_a? Array        # => true
c = [7,8,9]          # => [7, 8, 9] 
c.is_a? MyArray      # => false
d = a+c              # => [2, 2, 2, 7, 8, 9]
```

`super`, in `initialize`, is what gives your class instances the properties of an array. When `super` is invoked within any method, it invokes the parent class method of the same name. So here it calls `Array#initialize`. Moreover, `super` passes along all the parameters its method received; that is, you don't need to write

```
super args
```

You can do this with most most Ruby objects (e.g., hashes and strings), but there are some exceptions. In particular, you cannot subclass `Fixnum` or `Symbol`.